# ios - switch within navigation item bar

Tags: ios, storyboard, uinavigationitem, uiswitch

I want to set a `UISwitch` within a `UINavigationBar`. But when I try place my finger on the switch and drag it to "switch" on and off the view is not responding.

This is what i have.
https://github.com/rchampa/views-within-navigationItem

[image]

Comment: Github project has nothing in it its a empty view controller without any navigation controller embedded to it

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Exactly. I've just upload a simple demo. I've updated the description. Is not a logic problem, is a view problem. Did you run it?

Comment: @Ricardo Did _you_ run it? Your github demo project is _blank_. It has no navigation bar, no switch, no nothing. It's an empty window. Did you forget to commit and push the actual project?

Comment: Sorry. I forget push commits. Anyway I have solved my problem.

Comment: Cool, how did you solve it? Did the view have user interaction turned off? (That was going to be my guess.)

Comment: I'm still wondering what could happening. I've just remove all views from storyboard and start over.

Answer (score 5):

As already stated in the comments above your GitHub project does not contain any data. Nevertheless everything works as expected (and seems cleaner to me) if you set the custom `UIBarButtonItem` up programmatically:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupBarButtonItem()
}

private func setupBarButtonItem() {
    let offLabel = UILabel()
    offLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: UIFont.smallSystemFontSize)
    offLabel.text = "OFF"

    let onLabel = UILabel()
    onLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: UIFont.smallSystemFontSize)
    onLabel.text = "ON"

    let toggle = UISwitch()
    toggle.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [offLabel, toggle, onLabel])
    stackView.spacing = 8

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: stackView)
}

@objc func toggleValueChanged(_ toggle: UISwitch) {
    print("new value: \(toggle.isOn)")
}
```

[image: example]

**Update:**

I made it work via storyboard too. In contrast to setting it up programmatically you have to embed the `UIStackView` into a regular `UIView` to be able to add it as a `UIBarButtonItem` in storyboard. Then I added top, leading, bottom and trailing constraints (each with a constant of **0**) from the `UIStackView` to its superview. To get rid of the storyboard warnings and errors at design time (at runtime it works without any problems) you have to manually calculate and set the width for the outer view (which contains the `UIStackView`) that is needed to enclose all of it subviews (`offLabel.width` + `spacing` + `toggle.width` + `spacing` + `onLabel.width`).

[image: storyboard example]

Comment: Bravo. At the same time, it would still be very nice to know what's wrong with the OP's storyboard configuration.

Comment: Definitely. A project with the explicit configuration would help in that case. :)

Comment: How did you manage to add a View to the Bar button item? Xcode 10 doesn't allow me to drag&drop a view into the bar button item.

Comment: That's weird @DávidPásztor since Xcode 10 allows me to... Actually you do not have to d&d it into a bar button item but into the navigation bar (without a bar button item).

Comment: Glad I could help, @DávidPásztor :)